# When should I use nullChannel() instead of get() in Spring Integration DSL?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Can anyone provide a clear explanation of when to use nullChannel() vs. when to use get() when configuring a SI Flow with the DSL ?

Answer (score 2):

The `nullChannel()` is a shortcut of the `.channel(“nullChannel”).get()`. But it still has that logical purpose to give a clue for target developer that this is the end of the flow and we can’t continue processing after `nullChannel` since this channel cannot be subscribed for consuming messages sent to it.

If your confuse is why would one specify a `nullChannel` if there probably would be enough just have that `get()`, then the answer is: it is possible and a valid use-case when you rely on the `replyChannel` header to produce the result from your endpoint. But if you fully want to void that result, the `nullChannel` must be configured explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan. What I'm trying to get at is this. Why do I sometimes get an error if I end my flow without configuring this nullChannel whereas other times it's fine to omit it and end with a simple .get()? Which part of my DSL code is making it necessary to configure this null channel ? I can use the error message to give me a hint when I would need it, but I would rather understand what's really causing the error and what's the underlying design and idea that I'm not grasping yet. I'm assuming there are certain DSL methods that force me to configure this null channel? Which ones?

Comment: The `nullChannel` is just a particular sample of an output channel. There are one-way handlers and request-reply handlers. So, you definitely don't need to configure an output channel or think about a `replyChannel` header if that is a one-way one. If you'd like to return a result of request-reply handler to the caller in the beginning of the flow (an inbound gateway), then you also omit an output channel and rely on the `replyChannel` header. But if you'd like to continue the flow somewhere with that result, you configure an output on the replying endpoint. The `nullChannel` to stop the flow.